# feasible set if short selling of risk free asset is not allowed

Tags: portfolio-management, finance

I have 3 risky assets and one risk-free asset. From them I have to determine what the set of portfolios achievable looks like if there is short selling of risk-free asset is not allowed. What does this set looks like on a plane $(\mu,\sigma)?$

Comment: It looks like a segment starting at $(R_F,0)$ and ending at $T$ the tangency point on the Efficient Frontier. The Ray from $T$ to $\infty$ (i.e. the right half of the CML, beyond T) is not allowed because it involves selling the risk free asset (aka borrowing). https://pgpfm.wordpress.com/2015/08/28/fm-8-capital-market-line-ii/

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: I think, from the point T on out you can still have a frontier, but it is not a straight line (as noob2 stated). If you cannot short sell the risk free asset, you may nevertheless be allowed to shortsell another asset. In this case, the frontier from T forward looks like the "standard" frontiert (hyperbola).

Comment: will it be an area limited by hyperbolas? And additionally, the area bounded by two line from risk-free assets to points of tangency with hyperbola?